# How do I append date interval (date span) results into an PHP array?

Tags: php

Recordset when looped shows the results of the associated array.
[date] = startDate and [dateLast] = $endDate

Result:

```
2019-01-19 - 2019-01-22
2019-01-19 - 2019-01-23
2019-01-20 - 2019-01-25
2019-01-22 - 2019-01-25
2019-01-27 - 2019-01-30
2019-01-29 - 2019-01-31
2019-02-01 - 2019-02-05
```

Each row designates a booking start and end date. I want to generate a list of unique comma separated dates to use in a calendar.

Looping the same recordset I am trying to create an array of all the actual dates (start, end, and in between).

As I am looping a recordset, I am first using the first start and end date and putting those in an array.
Then using array_push to update that array with each records start and end dates. Then using array_unique to retain only unique values.

```
        <?php
    $wa_startindex = 0;
    while(!$reservALL->atEnd()) {
      $wa_startindex = $reservALL->Index;
    ?>

            <?php   
            $startDate = ($reservALL->getColumnVal("date")); 
            $endDate = ($reservALL->getColumnVal("dateLast")); 

            $format = "Y-m-d";

            $begin = new DateTime($startDate);
            $end = new DateTime($endDate);

            $interval = new DateInterval('P1D'); // 1 Day
            $dateRange = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end);

            $range = [];
            foreach ($dateRange as $date) {
                $range[] = $date->format($format);
                $result = array_unique($range, SORT_REGULAR);
            }
            ?>
            <?php
      $reservALL->moveNext();
    }
    $reservALL->moveFirst(); //return RS to first record
    unset($wa_startindex);
    unset($wa_repeatcount);
    ?>
```

But it seems to neglect many of the records as well as display repeating dates. Because the keys are preserved in array_unique that may explain the repeating records.

In any event the results of a print_r($result) show the following that is not what is expected. It's working but only showing the Last record and not appending each records Start End as well as in-between dates.

```
Array
(
  [0] => 2019-02-01
  [1] => 2019-02-02
  [2] => 2019-02-03
  [3] => 2019-02-04
)
```

Is the problem how that array is appended with array_push? It seems like it over writing rather than appending.

UPDATE TO SHOW FINAL CORRECT CODE:

```
<?php
    $wa_startindex = 0;
    $range = []; // declare Arry
    while(!$reservALL->atEnd()) {
      $wa_startindex = $reservALL->Index;
?>

            <?php   
            $startDate = ($reservALL->getColumnVal("date")); 
            $endDate = ($reservALL->getColumnVal("dateLast")); 

            $format = "m-d-Y";

            $begin = new DateTime($startDate);
            $end = new DateTime($endDate);

            $interval = new DateInterval('P1D'); // 1 Day
            $dateRange = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end);

            foreach ($dateRange as $date) {
                $range[] = $date->format($format);
            }
         array_push($range, $result);
            ?>
<?php
      $reservALL->moveNext();
    }
$result = array_filter(array_unique($range)); // array_filter removes any empty records
    $reservALL->moveFirst(); //return RS to first record
    unset($wa_startindex);
    unset($wa_repeatcount);
?>
```

Without the array_filter() applied there is a single empty record:

```
[0] => 01-10-2019
[1] => 01-11-2019
[2] => 01-12-2019
[3] => 01-13-2019
[4] => 
[15] => 01-19-2019
[16] => 01-20-2019
[17] => 01-21-2019
```

Today's date being "01-19-2019" suggests it may be related to the DateInterval('P1D').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first problem is that you are rewriting `$range` on every pass through the loop with this line:

```
$range = [];
```

You should move that line outside the loop. i.e.

```
$wa_startindex = 0;
$range = [];
while(!$reservALL->atEnd()) {
    ...
```

You also have issues with pushing data into `$range`. You are pushing arrays into it instead of single values. Change this code:

```
foreach ($dateRange as $date) {
    $range[] = $date->format($format);
    $result = array_unique($range, SORT_REGULAR);
}
array_push($range, $result);
```

to

```
foreach ($dateRange as $date) {
    $range[] = $date->format($format);
}
```

and then at the end of your loop, call `array_unique`:

```
    ...
}
$range = array_unique($range);
$reservALL->moveFirst(); //return RS to first record
```

Comment: This worked but there was a single empty record (not sure why). Solution was to add an array_filter() to the $result   --- $result = array_filter(array_unique($range));

Comment: @Burndogz that is really weird. The only values being pushed into `$range` should be formatted dates and since they are being generated from a `DatePeriod` object they should all be valid... it might be worth enabling error_reporting of `NOTICE` level errors to see if that shows something

Comment: Error reporting does not show anything but I believe the issue is related to Todays Date as that is where there is the single empty result. I'll update the original post to show this in context

Comment: @Burndogz have just noticed you still have `array_push($range, $result);` in your code. That shouldn't be there any more.

Comment: Yes removed the array_push and the empty result is gone!